# Tensorflow MCMC doesn't evolve chain states

Tags: python, tensorflow, mcmc, tensorflow-probability

I'm fairly new to tensorflow and MCMC in general. I'm doing a few basic calculations with different models, the most basic model converges without problem and gives good results from the MCMC calculation. However, when I use a more advanced model, I have a problem where the chain states are never evolved from the initial state.

I'm calling the sampler via this code:

```
    nkernel = tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
            target_log_prob_fn=_tf_lnlike,
            num_leapfrog_steps=5,
            step_size=0.1)
    adapt_kernel = tfp.mcmc.SimpleStepSizeAdaptation(
        inner_kernel=nkernel,
        num_adaptation_steps=num_burnin_steps,
        target_accept_prob=0.75)
    chains_states = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
        num_results=nresults,
        num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
        current_state=initial_state,
        kernel=adapt_kernel,
        trace_fn=None)
```

The likelihood function looks like this:

```
@tf.function
def _tf_lnlike(theta):
    y0 = tf.tensordot(tf.ones(theta.shape[0], dtype=dtype), data, axes=0)
    y0_err = tf.tensordot(tf.ones(theta.shape[0], dtype=dtype), data_err, axes=0)
    y_model = _tf_model(theta)
    return tf.math.reduce_sum(-0.5*((y_model-y0)/y0_err)**2, axis=1)
```

where `_tf_model` is a rather complex function (so I won't post it here). This is essentially trying to fit some input data (which are `tf.constant`). The first thing I checked was the gradients, which had `inf` or `nan` values from `_tf_model`. The simplest way I thought to solve that was to write a very simple numerical gradient function into the likelihiood function since the model is not analytically differentiable. `_tf_lnlike` now returns some reasonable gradients but I still have the same problem with the sampler. Honestly I'm not familiar enough with tf to even diagnose why it's not working so some suggestions for troubleshooting would be appreciated!

Edit: after some playing around it seems to be related to whether or not the model function calls `tf.reduce_sum` at any point.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say much without understanding what's inside `_tf_model`. If it has inf or nan values or gradients, that can be troublesome as you've already seen. But also if the curvature (second order derivatives) of the likelihood is very sharp, the log-likelihood can be extremely sensitive to any move so that any proposal would be rejected. Are there any constraints on `theta` (must be positive, etc)? If so, you may want to use `TransformedTransitionKernel` to enforce those.